# Как выполнить запрос из двух таблиц с оператором TABLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Выполняю задание:

> You must define a collection type to hold the attributes of a line item.
>   Then create a table to hold the invoice data including information about its line items. Do not define a separate table for item. Simply include the
>   attributes of any item that is referenced in a line item directly within the line item itself.
>   You need to create three invoices using the line item data shown below.

```sql
INVOICE# SHIPDATE TERMS ITEMID DESCRIPTION QUANTITY UNITPRICE LINETOTAL
-------- --------- --------------- ------- ---------------------------- -------- --------- ----------
INV001 27-APR-18 CREDIT A000100 GREEN WIDGET 1 35.10 35.10 
                        A000200 BLUE WIDGET 3 35.10 105.30

INV002 27-APR-18 Due on Receipt A001000 WHITE WIDGET 5 35.10 175.50
                                A000800 ORANGE THREE-HANDLED WIDGET 8 45.99 367.92
                                A000200 BLUE WIDGET 6 35.10 210.60
                                A000700 YELLOW THREE-HANDLED WIDGET 2 43.25 86.50
                                A000400 ORANGE WIDGET 1 45.99 45.99
INV003 27-APR-18 Due on Receipt
```

Затем, нужно следующим запросом получить список всех фактур и товаров в них:

```sql
SELECT LI.*
FROM INVOICE I, TABLE(I.LINEITEMS) LI;
```

Я создал [таблицы и заполнил их данными](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cacb503443bb162e03648370b3c53efd):

```sql
CREATE TABLE Invoice(
    INVOICE# VARCHAR(50) not null,
    SHIPDATE date,
    TERMS VARCHAR(50)
);
CREATE TABLE LineItems(
    ItemId VARCHAR(50)  not null,
    Quantity int  not null,
    Description VARCHAR(50) not null,
    UNITPRICE decimal (10,5) not null,
    LineTotal decimal (10,5) not null
);
```

Но когда я выполняю запрос, то получаю ошибку:

> ORA-00904: "I"."LINEITEMS": invalid identifier

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: В вашем задании вы должны создать коллекцию через `CREATE TYPE`. У вас пока обычные таблицы, для них слово `TABLE` не подходит.

Comment: @AlexR. спасибо за комментарий, но для меня пока это ясности не внесло:) Если я правильно понял Вас, то мне нужно создать  таблицу IVOICE и тип LINEITEMS? А как их потом соединить? Могли бы вы показать пример?

Comment: @AlexR. я создал тип данных - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3635186e024509b0fa59ba5a8465bebf, но  не понимаю, как связать его с INVOICE

Comment: Я с мобильного... см. Nested tables

Comment: @AlexR. да, я почитал документацию, но если честно, не особо понял. Буду очень признателен, если покажете пример, когда будете за ПК.

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Цитата из вашего комментария под ответом: _Я думал, что нужно каждый LINEITEMS добавлять отдельной строкой_,  [попытался развёрнуто ответить на это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1124083/217579).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вложенную таблицу надо [обьявить как столбец](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adobj/collection-data-types.html#GUID-2F2DD7A9-FC8B-4D79-9C19-4C15780A3ED5) в таблице `Invoice`. Таблица `LineItems` будет создана автоматически кaк указано в клаузе `STORE AS`. Вот так:

```sql
create or replace type LineItemT as object (
    ItemId varchar (50),
    Quantity int,
    Description varchar (50) ,
    UnitPrice decimal (10,5) ,
    LineTotal decimal (10,5)
    )
/    
create or replace type LineItemsТ as table of LineItemТ
/
create table Invoice (
    Invoice# varchar (50) not null,
    shipdate date,
    terms VARCHAR(50),
    LineItems LineItemsT 
)
nested table LineItems store as LineItems
/
```

Заполните данными и запрос будет работать:

```sql
insert into Invoice values (
    'INV001', date'27-04-18', 'CREDIT', 
    LineItemsT (LineItemT ('A000100', 1, 'GREEN WIDGET', 35.10, 35.10),
                LineItemT ('A000200', 6, 'BLUE WIDGET',  35.10, 210.60)));

select Invoice# invNo, li.* 
from invoice i, table (i.lineitems) li;

INVNO      ITEMID       QUANTITY DESCRIPTION       UNITPRICE  LINETOTAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------- ---------- ----------
INV001     A000100             1 GREEN WIDGET     35,1       35,1      
INV001     A000200             6 BLUE WIDGET      35,1       210,6
```

На [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5c2a077bf9a817b1d8d63370aa937a49).

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ!
теперь мне стало более понятно, как создаются типы. но в задании от меня требуют выполнить именно этот запрос ```SELECT LI.*
FROM INVOICE I, TABLE(I.LINEITEMS) LI;``` 
как мне наполнить значениями  LINEITEMS чтобы применить к нему table?

Comment: Пример полностью  рабочий. Он у вас не работает?  LineItems в нём заполняются из конструкторов.

Comment: работает. но мне нужно запустить вот этот запрос - ```SELECT LI.* FROM INVOICE I, TABLE(I.LINEITEMS) LI;``` - и он завершается с ошибкой - ```ORA-00942: table or view does not exist```
вот фиддл - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=af896b6433ef33fb3b550710a59ce863

Comment: Да, но вы же там таблицу INVOICE не создали. Разные фиддле между собой не общаются.

Comment: да, точно, упустил этот момент.
поправил фиддл - теперь другая ошибка ```ORA-00904: "I"."LINEITEMS": invalid identifier```
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ed386c4f8d55f5a83d6bdf19a7ed6a8e

Comment: может я не верно понимаю мое задание? но в условии написано так: ```With your collection type and table defined and populated, run the following queries.```
и указан этот запрос ```SELECT LI.*
FROM INVOICE I, TABLE(I.LINEITEMS) LI;```

Comment: как решить его, используя обычный join и таблицы я знаю. а как это запустить - нет:(

Comment: Там синтаксическая ошибка была. [Так работает](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4ac875680ae936ab112c50d9905c0609)

Comment: Под ошибкой вы имеете, что используется ```TABLE(I.LINEITEMS)``` вместо ```TABLE(LINEITEMS)```?
Но в моем задании почему-то именно так вызывается запрос. Если не сложно - посмотрите, пожалуйста (начало 5й страницы) - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bsqmG69TpDFhZF3wJfyl4dfrtJuCo4zw/view

Comment: Почитал боле внимательно задание. Вы всё с самого начала делали не так. Таблица INVOICE должна получить столбец  LINEITEMS.

Comment: если честно, то пока не понял, что именно я не так сделал и как сделать правильно:)
имеете ввиду, что каким-то образом необходимо в саму таблицу INVOICE добавить столбец LINEITEMS с типом LineItem?

Comment: Да, вот что вас просят [сделать](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ad1a1730e49bdba0294e106fa328d2d1). Данные сами заполните.

Comment: Спасибо! Заполнил все данными https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7f15ebcb0d2b532f52e10976cb44dc7d - все отработало, как и должно, кроме одного запроса - ```SELECT *
FROM TABLE(SELECT I.LINEITEMS
 FROM INVOICE I
 WHERE I.INVOICE# = 'INV002');``` - завершается с ошибкой ```single-row subquery returns more than one row```, хотя в задании говорится, что должен выполниться. Возможно, я снова не правильно понял условие?

Comment: Ха-ха, это уже другой вопрос. Уберите TABLE.

Comment: не помогло. да и черт с ним, вы и так уже много времени на меня потратили. еще раз - большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Хорошо, я посмотрю попозже (сейчас надо уезжать). Дайте ссылку на фиддле, где не получается.

Comment: фиддл - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0361f0c20c0b1f729ea880f156f22def в задании говорится, что т.к. указано условие ```WHERE I.INVOICE# = 'INV002'```, то запрос должен отработать.

Comment: Будте внимательней! А [так](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9f9454c074ca78c51d685041808e8015)?

Comment: Я думал, что нужно каждый LINEITEMS добавлять отдельной строкой. Понял свою ошибку, спасибо!

Comment: @0xdb а есть возможность в пример добавить две записи в `Invoice.LineItems` для *INV001*  и *INV002*, и показать какой будет результат.

Comment: @AlexR.  Добавил для INV001 две записи, для INV002 будет тоже самое. Или я не понял, что вы хотели спросить?

Comment: @0xdb спасибо. Теперь пример более полный, лучше для понимания.

Comment: @AlexR. Вот [пример с 2-мя платёжками](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0d197aff0a2ad5dde1e4d37e26c86cc3). Стоит ли дополнить ответ, вопрос в целом же не об этом? Запрос в вопросе стал бы рабочим даже без данных, просто  бы вернул - not found.

Comment: @0xdb Сейчас вижу, что INV002 уже лишнее. Но пример с двумя записями для INV001 очень хороший. Новичку трудно разобраться как вставлять записи. А без данных понять, что твой запрос работает правильно все таки тяжело. Сейчас ответ  оптимальный.