# Как изменить вложенную таблицу объявленную как столбец в другой таблице?

Tags: sql, oracle, коллекции

К [этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1123702/217579) было найдено решение, но появился [дополнительный вопрос в комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1123702/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-table/1123777#comment1941978_1123777).

После заполнения [данными исправленных таблиц](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c26395cc6f092b4287a6e3cff8901029):

```sql
insert into Invoice values (
    'INV001', date'27-04-18', 'CREDIT', 
    LineItemsT (LineItemT ('A000100', 1, 'GREEN WIDGET', 35.10, 35.10)));

insert into Invoice values (
    'INV001', date'27-04-18', 'CREDIT', 
    LineItemsT (LineItemT ('A000200', 3, 'BLUE WIDGET', 35.10, 105.30)));
```

Следующий запрос завершится с ошибкой:

```sql
select *
from table (select i.lineItems from Invoice i where i.Invoice# = 'INV001');
```

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

В подзапросе ожидается одна запись, но второй вставкой была добавлена ещё одна запись в таблицу `Invoice`, а не в `lineItems` как было задумано.

А как же добавить запись во вложенную таблицу объявленную как столбец, если запись в основной таблице уже существует?

Answer (score 2):

Для изменения вложенной таблицы объявленной как столбец, её надо сначало выбрать в подзапросе (другими словами, создать внутреннее представление).

Потом можно к ней добавить запись:

```sql
insert into Invoice values (
    'INV001', date'27-04-18', 'CREDIT', 
    LineItemsT (LineItemT ('A000100', 1, 'GREEN WIDGET', 35.10, 35.10)))
/
insert into table (
    select LineItems from Invoice i where i.Invoice# = 'INV001'
) values (LineItemT ('A000200', 3, 'BLUE WIDGET', 35.10, 105.30))
/
select *
from table (select i.lineItems from Invoice i where i.Invoice# = 'INV001');

ITEMID       QUANTITY DESCRIPTION       UNITPRICE  LINETOTAL
---------- ---------- ---------------- ---------- ----------
A000100             1 GREEN WIDGET     35,1       35,1      
A000200             3 BLUE WIDGET      35,1       105,3
```

А также, изменить или удалить запись:

```sql
update table (
    select LineItems li from Invoice i where i.Invoice# = 'INV001'
) li set li.Description = '*'||li.Description
where li.ItemId = 'A000200'; 
/
delete from table (
    select LineItems li from Invoice i where i.Invoice# = 'INV001'
) li where li.ItemId = 'A000100'; 
/
select *
from table (select i.lineItems from Invoice i where i.Invoice# = 'INV001');

ITEMID       QUANTITY DESCRIPTION       UNITPRICE  LINETOTAL
---------- ---------- ---------------- ---------- ----------
A000200             3 *BLUE WIDGET     35,1       105,3
```